# Cannot add multiple JPanel in JFrame,

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a following JFrame.

```
public class AddActivityWindow extends JFrame {

    //declaration of components go here
     ...
    public AddActivityWindow(ActivityStore store) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel pnl_date = new JPanel();
        JLabel lbl_date = new JLabel("X");
        pnl_date.add(lbl_date);
        add(pnl_date);


        pnl_activities = new JPanel();
        JLabel lbl_act = new JLabel("Y");
        pnl_activities.add(lbl_act);
        add(pnl_activities);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

When I create this Frame I was expecting that it would create a frame with two panels. But, I only see the second panel (i.e.) I only see `Y` on the screen and not `X`. However, if I remove the code for the second panel, then I can see `X`.

What happens when I add the second panel. Why does the first panel not show up in the frame?

Comment: Use some `layout` on JFrame before adding Panels to it, otherwise they will definitely overlap each other..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using a different Layout Manager, Have a look at : [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to select one for you.

This works fine for me ,

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FrameTest extends JFrame {

    public FrameTest() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(150, 150);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel pnl_date = new JPanel();
        JLabel lbl_date = new JLabel("X");
        pnl_date.add(lbl_date);
        add(pnl_date);


        JPanel pnl_activities = new JPanel();
        JLabel lbl_act = new JLabel("Y");
        pnl_activities.add(lbl_act);
        add(pnl_activities);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FrameTest().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The default layout of a `JFrame` is a `BorderLayout`. A characteristic of the `BorderLayout` is that it can only contain one component in each region. If you just use the `add` method without specifying any constraints, it is the same as adding the component to the `CENTER`. So your second `add` call replaces the element you first added.

Possible solutions: specify constraints, e.g

```
add(pnl_date, BorderLayout.NORTH);
//...
add(pnl_activities, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

or switch to another layout manager (e.g. a `BoxLayout` or a `FlowLayout`) for your `JFrame`. It depends on your needs. Take a look at the [Visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) which is a good starting point for choosing a manager.